# How to make webpack compile my new created files in new created directory

Tags: angularjs, webpack, thingsboard

I modify thingsboard ui and create a new directory "model-publish" and create some files under ./ui/src/app/ .

the files tree like below

```
./ui/src/app/model-publish/
├── index.js
├── model-publish.routes.js
└── model-publish.tpl.html
```

index.js:

```js
import ModelPublishRoutes from './model-publish.routes';

export default angular.module('thingsboard.modelPublish', [])
    .config(ModelPublishRoutes)
    .name;
```

model-publish.routes.js:

```js
import modelPublishTemplate from './model-publish.tpl.html'

/* eslint-enable import/no-unresolved, import/default */

/*@ngInject*/
export default function ModelPublishRoutes($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('home.modelPublishes', {
            url: '/modelPublish',
            module: 'private',
            auth: ['TENANT_ADMIN'],
            views: {
                "content@home": {
                    templateUrl: modelPublishTemplate
                }
            },
            data: {
                searchEnabled: false,
                pageTitle: 'audit-log.audit-logs'
            },
            ncyBreadcrumb: {
                label: '{"icon": "track_changes", "label": "audit-log.audit-logs"}'
            }
        });
}
```

model-publish.tpl.html:

```html
<h1>model publish</h1>
```

when I npm start , I find js files in the `model-publish` directory not compiled.

But if I put the the js files in already existed diretory , they are compiled correctly.

I am a new guy in front dev and very confused,  **Will Webpack or Angularjs not auto search all directories and files in src/app/ when compiling ?**

**How to make webpack compile my new created files in new created directory.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I bet you're not importing that new folder anywhere.

Webpack works by looking at your entrypoint file and finding all imports referenced there. And then it finds any import referenced by those imports and so on until it finds all dependencies. If your entry file doesn't either directly or indirectly reference that new folder, then webpack has no way of knowing it exists.

Comment: yes，thanks. I should import it in app. js. Maybe other similar modules import indirectly in app. js, so I need to print the dpendency tree to find how other import.

Comment: Cool, can you mark my answer as correct if it helped you?